# In PyQt5, how to avoid changing the Scaling Ratio of Computer Display to adapt to Screen Display?

Tags: python, pyqt5

My UI is like this(Yeah,I'm Chinese..).first picture is showed in Scaling Ratio of Computer 100%

[image]

But my program will run into problems on other people's computers.Like this:

second picture is showed Scaling Ratio of Computer 125%

[image]

And I find it is beacause the setting of computer:Scaling Ratio of Computer.like this in red box:

[image]

My pyqt5 program can only be displayed normally in Scaling Ratio of Computer 100%.How can I solve this problem?Many Thanks!

---

update

---

I've tried to use layout into my program.And new prolem arrises as showed in following picture. [it's about front size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhErf.png)What I want is a line with 25 words（汉字）.But with the Scaling Ratio of Computer Display changing, the front size changes.the number of One line words is less than 25.

Comment: If you use a layout you can make your program fully scaleable

Comment: @Thank you for your advice.And I've tried to use layout in my program.It solved some problems.But there is still one problem.I upload this the new problem picture.It's about font size.

Answer (score 0):

As Sam Taaghol sugested using a layout will scale your program no matter the resolution used. Here is an example program using a vertical layout:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MyForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showlcd)
        timer.start(1000)

        lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Clock", self)
        lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        myFont = QtGui.QFont()
        myFont.setBold(True)
        lbl.setFont(myFont)

        vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vLayout.addWidget(lbl)
        vLayout.addWidget(self.lcdNumber)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)

        self.showlcd()

    def showlcd(self):
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.lcdNumber.display(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```